# How can I track reactjs console errors when using webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, react-redux, webpack-dev-server

I'm following the [redux tutorial](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/) and using webpack to bundle the js files.

My problem is that console errors from React show the stack trace through the webpack bundle, while I would like them to show the stack trace through the actual js code.

E.g., I introduced a misspelling error in one of the js files to demonstrate. Here is the error in the Chromium console:
[Screenshot of current error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsBVf.png)

I'm aware of source maps, and I have them enabled. They allow me to add breakpoints and stuff, but they don't seem to allow error messages to be printed from the pre-bundled code.

Here is package.json:

```
{
  "name": "feedmeapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.6.5",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "eslint": "^2.13.1",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.1.1",
    "webpack": "^1.12.13",
    "webpack-bundle-tracker": "0.0.93",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "es6-promise": "^3.1.2",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.5.1",
    "radium": "^0.16.6",
    "react-cookie": "^0.4.5",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.0",
    "redux": "^3.3.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^1.0.3"
  }
}
```

Here is my two-tiered webpack config:

```
//webpack.base.config.js

var path = require("path")
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,

  entry: {
    // Add as many entry points as you have container-react-components here
    App1: './reactjs/App1',
    vendors: ['react'],
  },

  output: {
      path: path.resolve('./feedmeapp/static/bundles/local/'),
      filename: "[name]-[hash].js"
  },

  externals: [
  ], // add all vendor libs

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendors', 'vendors.js'),
  ], // add all common plugins here

  module: {
    loaders: [] // add all common loaders here
  },

  resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'bower_components'],
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
}
```

Second File:

```
// webpack.local.config.js

var path = require("path")
var webpack = require('webpack')
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')
var config = require('./webpack.base.config.js')

var ip = 'localhost'
config.devtool = "#eval-source-map"
config.output.publicPath = 'http://' + ip + ':3000' + '/assets/bundles/'

config.plugins = config.plugins.concat([
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
  new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats-local.json'}),
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
      'BASE_API_URL': JSON.stringify('http://'+ ip +':8000'),
  }}),
])

config.module.loaders.push(
  { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'] }
)

config.entry = {
  App1: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://' + ip + ':3000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './reactjs/App1',
  ],
}

module.exports = config
```

I'm bundling this using a simple webpack dev server that hot reloads the bundles.

```
//server.js

var webpack = require('webpack')
var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server')
var config = require('./webpack.local.config')

new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
  hot: true,
  inline: true,
  historyApiFallback: true,
}).listen(3000, config.ip, function (err, result) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }

  console.log('Listening at ' + config.ip + ':3000')
})
```

This workflow comes from a tutorial on using react with django by @mbrochh.

The bundles are loaded as static assets into a django template which will be running my whole project. However, I don't believe that any of the django code would affect what I'm trying to do with the error messages.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you post your package.json file too?

Comment: Added package.json @NevinMadhukarK

Comment: Is there a typo on the 'SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER' ?

Comment: @NevinMadhukarK there is, but I just introduced the typo to demonstrate the type of error message that I receive. The desired result is to get the console to show the original file containing the error and not the webpack bundle.

Comment: If my answer helped you please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a source mapping plugin, https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/

It will map your debugging/console lines to the actual lines of code. It will create much bigger bundles though.